# Embed iframe [Google Sheet] not scrolling on android

Tags: iframe, scroll

I am not a coder at all, so I would like to ask for help.

I want to put an embed Google Sheet on my webpage. I am using Webnode to do so.

It's working fine, but when I try scrolling it on my phone (to see the left part of that as well), it does nothing. :( What should I change in the code? Thank you in advance!

The code is here:

Comment: <iframe width="468" height="420" src="link/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>

Comment: I've already tried adding &chrome=false in a bunch of ways, but then it says that it can't load the site... :/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it! Instead of using a fixed width, I used: width="100%". Now I can scroll it on phone as well. :D